# A post request with custom parameters in SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, post, alamofire

I got a problem with Alamofire post request what if I have a parameters like :

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        [["x": 1],["y": 2]],
        [["x": 1],["y": 2]],
        [["x": 1],["y": 2]]
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters)
```

the post request won't work ! do you have any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: do you mean "baz" : ["a" : 1]  ??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send that structure as form encoded in the http request body. Maybe you'd like to send it as json. In that case you can invoke request method like this:

`Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)`

Answer (score 0):

Such variant works

```
let parameters = [
            "foo": "bar",
            "baz": ["a", 1],
            "qux": [
                [["x": 1],["y": 2]],
                [["x": 1],["y": 2]],
                [["x": 1],["y": 2]]
            ]
        ]
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted,error:nil)

        let post = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

        httpPost("http://httpbin.org/post", postData: post){res, code in
            println(res)
        }
```

//place function code upper the action where you posting your data

```
 func httpPost(url:String, postData: String, completion: (String, Int) -> Void) {

            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.addValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("gzip, deflate, sdch", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.addValue("max-age=0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            completion(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String, statusCode)
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
```